# Is there a PHP class that helps to embed IPTC data into JPEG?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP class that helps to embed IPTC data into JPEG?

Comment: Yeap, here: [EXIF information reader and writer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1042-PHP-EXIF-information-reader-and-writer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Georg Engist](http://www.georg-engist.de/set-iptc-data-in-jpeg/)'s effort.

Answer (score 0):

follows this class I made to deal with "IPTC" https://github.com/agutoli/Image_Iptc

```php
require 'Iptc.php';

$iptc = new Iptc('logo_php.jpg');
$iptc->set(Iptc::KEYWORDS,array(
    'keyword1','keyword2'
));
$iptc->write();
```

hug!

Answer (score 0):

This class is very efficient to handle the iptc of images, take a look if it helps ...

https://github.com/agutoli/Image_Iptc

```
$this->_iptc = new Iptc('../logo_php.jpg');
$this->_iptc->set(Iptc::OBJECT_NAME, 'test');
$this->_iptc->write();
```